# How to use GEOS library create a polygon?

Tags: c++, 3d, geometry, polygon

I want to use GEOS find simple polygons from a set of line segment, but I am confused on use GEOS library, is there some advice?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27643210/how-do-i-make-a-rectangle-in-geos) thread addresses your question.